# How to calculate a mean depending on another logical column using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm a newbie to R. I'm trying to use a group_by on a table to produce a mean value based on another logical column.

Here is a sample dataset:

```
   code   value datedate   dummytime Morning Afternoon Evening
   <chr> <dbl> <chr>      <chr>     <lgl>   <lgl>     <lgl>  
  1 G002   4.59 2020-05-01 05:00:00  FALSE   FALSE     FALSE  
  2 G002   3.84 2020-05-01 05:30:00  FALSE   FALSE     FALSE  
  3 G002   3.61 2020-05-01 06:00:00  TRUE    FALSE     FALSE  
  4 G002   3.51 2020-05-01 06:30:00  TRUE    FALSE     FALSE  
  5 G002   3.31 2020-05-01 07:00:00  TRUE    FALSE     FALSE  
  6 G002   3.12 2020-05-01 07:30:00  FALSE   FALSE     FALSE  
  7 G002   5.04 2020-05-01 08:00:00  FALSE   FALSE     FALSE  
  8 G002   4.82 2020-05-01 08:30:00  FALSE   FALSE     FALSE  
  9 G002   4.33 2020-05-01 09:00:00  FALSE   FALSE     FALSE  
 10 G002   4.59 2020-05-01 09:30:00  FALSE   FALSE     FALSE
 11 G002   3.84 2020-05-01 10:00:00  FALSE   FALSE     FALSE
 12 G002   3.61 2020-05-01 10:30:00  FALSE   FALSE     FALSE
 13 G002   3.51 2020-05-01 11:00:00  FALSE   FALSE     FALSE
 14 G002   3.31 2020-05-01 11:30:00  FALSE   FALSE     FALSE
 15 G002   3.12 2020-05-01 12:00:00  FALSE   FALSE     FALSE
 16 G002   5.04 2020-05-01 12:30:00  FALSE   TRUE      FALSE
 17 G002   4.82 2020-05-01 13:00:00  FALSE   TRUE      FALSE
 18 G002   4.33 2020-05-01 13:30:00  FALSE   TRUE      FALSE
```

Is there a simple way using dplyr to produce a result like so:

```
code meanMorning meanAfternoon meanEvening
G002 3.48        4.73          NA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `summarise_at` to apply a function to multiple columns.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(code) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(Morning:Evening), list(mean = ~mean(value[.], na.rm = TRUE)))

# A tibble: 1 x 4
#  code  Morning_mean Afternoon_mean Evening_mean
#  <chr>        <dbl>          <dbl>        <dbl>
#1 G002          3.48           4.73          NaN
```

Note that `summarise_at` is soon going to replaced with `across` in the next release of `dplyr`.

Comment: Great, thanks for the response! Is it possible to combine this summarise with a maximum value column?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by maximum value column?

Comment: How is it possible to combine your solution with other summarises that I may want to do. For example if I want to add: summarise(MaxFlow = max(value)).

Comment: as far as I am aware it is not possible to do this in one `summarise`.(although it will be possible with `across`). For now, you can do something like `df %>%
  group_by(code) %>%
  group_by(MaxFlow = max(value), add = TRUE) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(Morning:Evening), list(mean = ~mean(value[.], na.rm = TRUE)))`